# How does the biasing work in a JFET based triangle to sinewave converter?

Tags: transistors, analog, jfet

To those who haven't see this cool little circuit it employs the non-linearity and symmetry of the JEFET to clip a triangular signal to make it more sinusoidal

[image: JFET Traingle 'cipper']

Can someone please explain to me how the biasing in this circuit works?

Comment: Ok.  **That** is a cool hack.

Comment: Note that the biasing isn't constant. Vgen can be positive and negative. When Vgen = 0 V, there is no biasing. An interesting circuit to try on a rainy Sunday afternoon though. I might try it out if I can find a working JFET in my parts drawer.

Comment: However, one should know that this circuit works "good" for a certain input amplitude only (app. +/- 2V).

Comment: [Might help.](http://www.timstinchcombe.co.uk/index.php?pge=a110#mrnotes)